# Regular Expression for redirect

Tags: regex, wordpress

How do I redirect all the following URLs to "/" using single regular expression?

- members/kaleem/
- members/kaleem/activity/just-me/
- members/kaleem/activity/
- members/kaleem/activity/favorites/
- members/kaleem/activity/groups/
- members/kaleem/friends/

I am using it wordpress redirect plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Wordpress' redirect plugin works, but this regular expression will match all of above, as well as any other pages after `members/kaleem`.

```
members/kaleem[[\w\-\/]*
```

Grab word characters, dashes, and slashes that appear after `members/kaleem`.  If there are certain pages after `members/kaleem` that *shouldn't* be matched, it get's more complicated.  I was assuming that the examples you showed were part of a pattern.

If you want to only match `kaleem/activity` and `kaleem/friends`, plus any pages that are children of them, you can use this:

```
members/kaleem/((activity|friends)[\w\/\-]*)?
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems `members/` is the common identifier. Correct? If so, you just have to match that: `^members/`. Otherwise it becomes a bit more complicated: `^members/kaleem/(?:friends|activity/(?:(?:just-me|favorites|groups)/)?)`. See: http://regex101.com/r/jJ4rM8